# puppet error Error: Could not request certificate: SSL_connect

Tags: puppet

I was able to sign cert created by client

1st time

opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent -t

..
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled

Then i go to server

puppetserver ca sign  --all

now running again at client

/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent -t error

Error: Could not request certificate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [self signed certificate in certificate chain for /CN=Puppet Root CA: bf86bea205b379]

i did ssl dir move & re-create cert but then it goes to same loop .. ie server sign fine , but agent fails again

Any suggestions Please

OS centos 7

client 
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet --version
4.10.12

server 
puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 6.11.0

thanks

Comment: upgrade client or downgrade server as a first step - 4x is very old - try 6x

Comment: Yes that helped, i did client upgrade !!! thanks